# Will WMTS clients accept redirect (code 307) responses for getTile operations?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

We have all of our tiles available via AWS cloudfront. Cloudfront provides local caches of data, to speed up requests from geographically dispersed clients.

WMTS `gettile` operations typically return the tile (in say, a jpeg or png) straight to the client. However, instead of piping (via node) the tile straight back to the client, we want to redirect them to the cloudfront URL for that tile (which we has to sign, to confirm they can legitimately access the tile).

Does anyone know if WMTS clients will access this sort of redirect?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of Arc Desktop's http client, the answer to this question is yes.